# PyQt5 emit clicked signal on Qtextedit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtextedit

My qtextedit field has some predefined text in it.
I would like to make it disappear as soon as it is clicked.
So im trying to create a "clicked" signal for it. Here is what i have (just important lines:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

(...)

```
class QTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        self.clicked.emit()
```

(...)

```
    self.userfield = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.userfield.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 30))
    self.userfield.setObjectName("userfield")
    self.userfield.clicked.connect(lambda: self.txt())
```

I get AttributeError: 'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'clicked'

I can provide the rest of the code, but it is just an unfunctional ui for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call a class equal to another existing class, that can cause you conflicts and therefore many problems.

Apart from that in the following code:

```
self.userfield = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

You are telling them to use the QTextEdit from QtWidgets module and not your class.

**Solution:**

```
# ...
class TextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        self.clicked.emit()
# ...
    self.userfield = TextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.userfield.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 30))
    self.userfield.setObjectName("userfield")
    self.userfield.clicked.connect(self.txt)
    # ...
```

Comment: Oh of course! thank you!
I've read a lot about event filter, would that be a better solution to this? or is this way okay?

Comment: @wrong1man Both are equivalent, I use eventFilter when I can not overwrite the class.